# Can an Option in a Select tag takes multiple values?

Tags: html, node.js

```html
<select name="Testing">  
  <option value="1" value="2010"> One  
  <option value="2" value="2122"> Two  
  <option value="3" value="0"> Three
</select>
```

If can explain how can work with nodejs for get the multi value.

Comment: What are you trying to do in making a select tag with multiple values? What would it look like?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this a number of ways, one such way is this.

```html
    <select name="">
        <option value='{"num_sequence":[0,1,2,3]}'>Option one</option>
        <option value='{"foo":"bar","one":"two"}'>Option two</option>
    </select>
```

Another option is using optgroups as seen here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup